Issues with chapter/section/part customisation
I have this problem when I try to customise my chapters/sections :

Furthermore, I'd like to center my Part number down here:

I use this code for each category :
\newlength\rulewp
\titleformat{\part}[block]
{\filleft\sffamily\bfseries}
{\fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont\textcolor{VioletRed4!80!}{\thepart}\hskip8mm\titlerule[0.pt]}
{0em}
{\fontsize{40}{42}\bfseries\llap{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\filright#1\vskip-5.ex}}}%
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-45pt}{18ex}

\newlength\rulew
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\filleft\sffamily\bfseries}
{\fontsize{120}{120}\selectfont\textcolor{VioletRed4!80!}{\thechapter}\hskip8mm\titlerule[0.8pt]}
{0em}
{\fontsize{25}{27}\bfseries\llap{\parbox[b]{.75\linewidth}{\filright#1\vskip0.6ex}}}%
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-45pt}{18ex}

\newlength\rulewsect
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\filleft\sffamily\bfseries}
{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont\textcolor{VioletRed4!80!}{\thesection}\hskip8mm\titlerule[0.8pt]}
{0em}
{\fontsize{18}{20}\bfseries\llap{\parbox[b]{0.85\linewidth}{\filright#1\vskip0.6ex}}}%
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{-45pt}{5ex}

\newlength\rulewsubsect
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\filleft\sffamily\bfseries}
{\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont\textcolor{VioletRed4!80!}{\thesubsection}\hskip8mm\titlerule[0.pt]}
{0em}
{\fontsize{15}{17}\bfseries\llap{\parbox[b]{0.85\linewidth}{\filright#1\vskip0.ex}}}%
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{-45pt}{2ex}

Thank you in advance for your help.

As always here, please provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here there is no document class, no preamble....

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Remove those negative space and put even space before after \titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{10pt}{10pt}

I found the solution to the first problem by removing the part that specifies title spacing :
\titlespacing*{\part}{0pt}{-45pt}{18ex}

But I still don't know how to center the part number (the roman number I to be at the center). Some complained about not putting the
\documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \usepackage{amssymb}https://www.overleaf.com/project/63569127f04bd5167bad8704
\usepackage{color} % où xcolor selon l'installation
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\definecolor{Prune}{RGB}{99,0,60}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{multirow} %% Pour mettre un texte sur plusieurs rangées
\usepackage{multicol} %% Pour mettre un texte sur plusieurs colonnes
\usepackage{scrextend} %Forcer la 4eme  de couverture en page pair
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} 
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum} % à retirer!!!


\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%

\newlength\rulewp
\titleformat{\part}[block]
{\filleft\sffamily\bfseries}
{\fontsize{117}{117}\selectfont\textcolor{VioletRed4!80!}{\thepart}\hskip8mm\titlerule[0.pt]}
{0em}
{\fontsize{35}{37}\bfseries\llap{\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\filright#1\vskip-5.ex}}}%

\begin{document}
\part{Introduction}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!
